# Remove text from a PHP string

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code being echoed:

```
[caption id="attachment_13" align="alignnone" width="235" caption="Event 1"]
   <img src="image.png" />
[/caption]
```

I only want the `img` tag to be echoed.

I've tried using `<?php echo strip_tags($value, '<img>'); ?>` but because the [caption] tag isn't actually a proper HTML tag I don't know how to remove it.  Is there a function which will remove the text from a string?

Would `str_replace` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually, regular expression is not recommended for HTML parsing.  But if you just want something quick, you can use:

```
<?php

$s = '[caption id="attachment_13" align="alignnone" width="235" caption="Event 1"]
   <img src="image.png" />
[/caption] ';

if (preg_match('/<img[^>]*>/', $s, $matches)) echo $matches[0];

?>
```

output:

```
<img src="image.png" />
```

Comment: This worked great. The problem was that the string wasn't being parsed by Wordpress. To parse the caption tag, you need to add this code: `apply_filters('the_content', $value);`

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/\<img src=[^\>]+\>/', $value, $imgTag);
echo $imgTag[0];
```

Comment: That'll output `Array`, so, if there's just one match use `echo $imgTag[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$str = "[caption id="attachment_13" align="alignnone" width="235" caption="Event 1"]
   <img src="image.png" />
[/caption] ";
$arr = explode ( '<img' , $str);
$arr2 = explode ( '>' , $arr[1]);

echo '<img' . $arr2[0] . '>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, however, change the `[]` with `<>` and then do the `strip_tags`

```
$replaceThis = array('[', ']');
$withThis = array('<', '>');
echo strip_tags(str_replace($replaceThis, $withThis, $value), '<img>');
```

Answer (score 0):

try some regexp : 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

something like that something should work with minimum adaptation (i don't work with PHP since a long long long time xD) :

```
<?php
$pattern = '/.*(<img[^>]+)>.*/';
$remplacement = '$1';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $value);
?>
```